# How to pre-select phone code based on country select in angular 4/angular 2?

Tags: angular

I need to get a Country select dropdown and based on Country select, the below input box for phone number should automatically pre-select the mobile number code based on country.

Comment: Please show us that you made an effort yourself and post some code.

Answer (score 0):

This is some sample code you can use.

HTML

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"> 
    <option [value]="c.code" *ngFor="let c of countries">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" />
```

This code is compatible with angular 2 and above.

Typescript

```
  countries = [
    { code: "+12", name: "United States" },
    { code: "+13", name: "Australia" },
    { code: "+14", name: "Canada" },
    { code: "+15", name: "Brazil" },
    { code: "+16", name: "England" }
  ];
  selectedValue: any;
```